# Trying to round part of shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

I know you can use `border-radius` to round objects with CSS, but I am trying to figure out how to round, or possibly hide, the pointed parts of a CSS shape when overlaying over a circle:

It's tough to explain without a Codepen:

http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/gpEdJo

```
#circle:before { 
  position:absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -25px;
  z-index: 100;
  content: "";
  border-right: 35px solid white;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

In the Codepen you can see the circle and where parts of the white are overflowing the red boundary of it. The goal is to get rid of the white points and round the white perfectly with the red OR make the section of the circle that the white overlays completely transparent (like taking a slice from a pizza).

Comment: Yeah. It is kinda hard to follow the question but could any one of this help http://jsfiddle.net/index/Em8wx/ ?

Comment: you mean you want that white triangle to be aligned with the circle ? or removed completely ?

Comment: Either solution works. I am trying to either align it with the circle or make that part of the circle completely transparent.

Comment: @cfly24: What you can do is change the border color same as that of background's ..hope that helps.. Please see  the pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNwRNd

Comment: Thats what I was doing, but the background I'm hoping to use changes colors slightly and the points are visible

Comment: @cfly24 so you can change the border color too..Is there any  problem with that ?

Comment: Yeah, I mean the background changes dynamically while on the page

Comment: @cfly24: Using `border` property to create such effects is always tricky because they don't respond to `overflow` settings etc. Would you be fine with an entirely different approach producing the same shape?

Comment: Yeah, anything that will produce the effect I'm trying to produce will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does border-radius not work for my case?**

Yes, `border-radius` property can be used to produce circles but it can produce a proper circle only when the `height` and `width` are the same. In your original sample, the `height` and `width` of the element is determined by the thickness of the `border` on the `::before` element and since the border on one side is thicker than the rest, it produces a rectangle instead of a square. Because of this you would only get a oval at best  and not a circle.

Even if you make the border thickness the same, the curvature of the round wouldn't match with the curvature of the outer circle (parent container) because the radii and center points are both different.

I have changed the `border-color` of the other three borders in the below snippet to help you visualize what is going on:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
#circle {
  border-right: 50px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid red;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 50px;
}
#circle:after {
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
  z-index: 100;
  content: "";
  border: 25px solid yellow;
}
#circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -25px;
  z-index: 101;
  content: "";
  border-right: 35px solid white;
  border-top: 25px solid cyan;
  border-bottom: 25px solid cyan;
  border-left: 25px solid cyan;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

One other method that is typically used to cut out the extraneous part is `overflow: hidden` but that also wouldn't work for your case because your outer circle is created only by `border` and it doesn't actually have any content height or content width. Because of this when you add `overflow: hidden` your pseudo elements would get totally hidden.

---

**What are the other options that I could use?**

Here is an alternate approach to create the same shape as you originally intended to with just a single element + two pseudo-elements.

The shape consists of the following components:

- A container element which is converted into a circle by using `border-radius: 50%`.
- One pseudo-element with dimensions half that of the parent and `border-radius: 50%` to produce the inner circle. A `z-index: 1` is added to position this above the sliced area.
- Another pseudo-element which has a `transform: rotate(45deg)` added to produce the slice.
- Parent container has `overflow: hidden` which prevents the other parts of the pseudo-element from showing up.

<sup>**Note:** I assume you won't be having any concerns using `transform` because you had tagged CSS3.</sup>

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
#circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#circle:before, #circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#circle:before {
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#circle:after {
  right: 0px;
  background: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

---

**How to get a transparent slice?** (like the Colorado flag)

Alternately, if you want the slice to be transparent totally then you can use the below approach:

- Here the container has a bit of padding and the background of the container is made small by restricting it to only the `content-box` using `background-clip`. This forms the inner yellow circle.
- The outer red circle is made up of two pseudo-elements each of which have a background color only for half portion through `linear-gradient`. The other half is transparent.
- The two pseudo-elements are rotated in opposing directions to make it look as though they leave a transparent cut in between.

  ```css
  body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(64, 64, 150) 33%, white 33%, white 66%, rgb(64, 64, 150) 66%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 260px;
  }
  #circle {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: rgb(255, 243, 21);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-clip: content-box;
  }
  #circle:after,
  #circle:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  #circle:before {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(237, 51, 56) 50%, transparent 50%);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #circle:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(237, 51, 56) 50%, transparent 50%);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="circle"></div>
  ```
- If you don't want to use `linear-gradient` to produce semi-circles then you can create the same effect by using two pseudo-elements whose height is half their width and assign the appropriate `border-radius` to it.

  ```css
  body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(64, 64, 150) 33%, white 33%, white 66%, rgb(64, 64, 150) 66%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 260px;
  }
  #circle {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: rgb(255, 243, 21);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-clip: content-box;
  }
  #circle:after,
  #circle:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: rgb(237, 51, 56);
    border-radius: 100px 100px 0px 0px;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  #circle:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #circle:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="circle"></div>
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a pseudo element, and using borders on the pseudo to manipulate the shape to your liking. This uses the `transparent` border color on the right side, with the rest with a solid color. A demo of this is shown below:

```css
html {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/900);
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gold;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 50px solid red;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If the angle here is too big for your liking, you could duplictate the pseudo element on an `:after` element, and using `transform:rotate(x deg);` to rotate to a specific angle

A demo of this can be seen when hovering below:

```css
html {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/900);
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gold;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
div:before, div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 50px solid red;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
div:hover:after{
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  }
div:hover:before{
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the approach. Stop using `:before` and `:after`, and use `overflow: hidden` plus `z-index` layering with multiple elements.

The new HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-circle"></div>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}

.inner-circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.triangle {
    position:absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    border-right: 105px solid purple;
    border-top: 75px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
    border-left: 75px solid transparent;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Check the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ghv02ucr/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've checked on your question, try this code on your **#circle:before**, and you will see the triangle aligned;

```
 #circle:before { 
  position:absolute;
  left: -18px;
  top: -25px;
  z-index: 100;
  content: "";
  border-right: 35px solid white;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

Or you can eliminate all the **#circle:before** properties to get rid of the triangle.... hope it helped.